# can I keep and post my art of human beings on social media if I made it in a time I didn't know it was haram?

Tags: drawing, art

I used to draw pictures of living souls, but when I found out it wasn't permissible I stoped. but I kept them and still post my art on social media. I want to know if I should keep them, destroy them or if I can sell them. I don't want to do anything that's not permissible but if I could keep them I would love that.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you shouldn't post it on social media because someone else would might get inspired by your work and start making sketches of living souls and if they do then you'll be held responsible. Secondly you shouldn't store/keep them as well because from time to time you might be looking at them and **satan** might persuade you start making sketches again because we as human beings are are very weak creatures and our conscience isn't constant all the time. So it's better and recommended that we close all the direct and indirect doors that could lead us astray.